# Show one input and hide another one

Tags: jquery

I have in a page many inputs and i want to display just one until you press enter. When you press enter the current input disappears and a hidden input shows up.

```
<input type="text" value="Name" />
<input type="text" value="Password" />
```

And here is the jQuery code:

```
$('input').each(function(){

    $(this).fadeIn();

        $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) 
                return true;
            else return false;

        });
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

I made this piece of script but it does not work. It shows me both inputs in the same time , then disappear.

What should I change to get the desired results?

Comment: What you're trying to do is totally what the user does not expect. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Why not? It's something different.

Comment: Why not? Forms. We all know how they work. A lot of us know tab gets you from one field to the next. But oh on that particular site out of millions, yeah you need to press what you normally would to submit the form to get to the next field. Unique is one thing, against-convention for such a simple function is another ball game entirely. I would strongly advise against this.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/z7ZNL/1/

```
<input type="text" value="Name" />
<input type="text" value="Password" style="display: none;" />

$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) 
    $('input').not(this).fadeIn();
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

This is only enough code to handle two inputs. Your description mentions "many". For that you'd need some sort of counter or place marker to cycle through all elements.

I agree with popnoodles. This is odd behavior. Use with caution.